# Associative Array with List of Files as Values …

Tags: arrays, bash, dictionary, hashtable, associative-array

I'm having some Trouble with Bash's associative Arrays: I'm looking for a Solution to assign an Array with Filenames to the associative Array.

It should look like :

```
/Applications/Setup.app => ([0] = "/Applications/Setup.app/IDStore@2x.png"
                            [1] = "/Applications/Setup.app/IDMessages@2x.png"
                            [2] = "/Applications/Setup.app/IDMusic New@2x.png")
```

Declaring the Dictionary / Hash Table / Associative Array isn't the Problem :

```
declare -A Dictionary
```

To get the Keys I'm using "readarray", combined with "find" :

```
readarray -d '' Applications < <(find "/Applications" -name "*.app" -print0)
```

If a Directory has a Whitespace in it's Name it's not a Problem. Now I need to find the PNG-Files in Application's Directory :

```
if [ ${#Applications[*]} -gt 0 ]; then
    for App in "${Applications[@]}"; do
        readarray -d '' Files < <(find "$App" -iname "*.png" -type f -print0)

        for File in "${Files[@]}"; do
            Dictionary["$App"]+="$File"
        done
    done
fi
```

The Problem which I didn't understand is, how can I add the Result of second "find" to the declared associative Array as List of Files ? If I set the readarray with Delimiter ' ' some Files, containing Whitespaces, were broken.

The next Question is how can I get the Values in a for-Loop ? I tried this also with readarray, but this didn't work for Files with Whitespaces in it's Name.

```
for Key in "${!Dictionary[@]}"; do
    readarray -d ' ' Values <<< "${Dictionary[$Key]}"

    for Value in "${Values[@]}"; do
        echo "$Value"
    done
done
```

If I run the above Script this is what I get :

```
/Applications/Setup.app/IDStore@2x.png/Applications/Setup.app/IDMessages@2x.png/Applications/Setup.app/IDMusic 
New@2x.png
```

But I want this One :

```
/Applications/Setup.app/IDStore@2x.png
/Applications/Setup.app/IDMessages@2x.png
/Applications/Setup.app/IDMusic New@2x.png
```

Is there any Chance getting this Work with Bash 5.0.3 ?

The Goal is to use most of the Features without awk / grep / sed, so it runs with Bash's Built-In Commands.

Comment: The only idea I have is to store the lists in a format like JSON, using a tool like `jq`. But really, if you need 2-dimensional arrays, you shouldn't be using `bash` in the first place. Use a programming language with real data structures.

Answer (score 0):

When populating the array with the filenames, consider using a character (as a delimiter) that does not exist in any of the filenames. [**NOTE**: as currently coded there is no delimiter hence the reason the filenames are jammed together as a single long line].

For example, assuming the filenames do not contain a linefeed (`\n`), and assuming the `find` returns the following:

```
/Applications/Setup.app/IDStore@2x.png
/Applications/Setup.app/IDMessages@2x.png
/Applications/Setup.app/IDMusic New@2x.png
```

We can populate the array like such:

```
unset      Dictionary
declare -A Dictionary

App="/Applications/Setup.app"

# for sake of example, simulate find results by processing a list of files

for file in "/Applications/Setup.app/IDStore@2x.png" "/Applications/Setup.app/IDMessages@2x.png" "/Applications/Setup.app/IDMusic New@2x.png"
do
    Dictionary[${App}]+=$'\n'"${file}"     # use '\n' as delimiter
done

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do
    [[ -n "${line}" ]] &&                  # skip the initial '\n'
    printf "|%s|\n" "${line}"
done <<< "${Dictionary[@]}"
```

**NOTE**: pipes added to `printf` format as visual delimiters

This generates:

```
|/Applications/Setup.app/IDStore@2x.png|
|/Applications/Setup.app/IDMessages@2x.png|
|/Applications/Setup.app/IDMusic New@2x.png|
```

Answer (score 0):

Aray of arrays, consider this approach:

```
[[ ${Applications[@]} ]] && {
    for i in "${!Applications[@]}"; do
        readarray -d '' "Files$i" < <(find "${Applications[$i]}" -iname "*.png" -type f -print0)
        Dictionary["${Applications[$i]}"]="Files$i"
    done
}
```

And then to retrive values use this:

```
for key in "${!Dictionary[@]}"; do
    val="${Dictionary[$key]}[@]"
    echo "$key: ${!val}"
done
```

And check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63350479/iterate-over-array-of-array-names-expanding-each-to-its-members)

Answer (score 0):

By just modifying Ivan's nice answer, how about:

```
declare -A Dictionary
readarray -d '' Applications < <(find "/Applications" -name "*.app" -print0)

for i in "${!Applications[@]}"; do
    readarray -d '' "Files$i" < <(find "${Applications[$i]}" -iname "*.png" -type f -print0)
    Dictionary["${Applications[$i]}"]="Files$i"
done

for key in "${!Dictionary[@]}"; do
    echo "$key => "
    declare -n ary="${Dictionary[$key]}"
    for j in "${!ary[@]}"; do
        echo "  [$j] = ${ary[j]}"
    done
done
```

As an example, if we have a directory tree as follows:

```
/Applications/
├── Bar.app
│   ├── bar1.png
│   └── bar2.png
├── Foo.app
│   ├── foo1.png
│   └── foo2.png
└── Setup.app
    ├── IDMessages@2x.png
    ├── IDMusic New@2x.png
    └── IDStore@2x.png
```

The result will be:

```
/Applications/Foo.app => 
  [0] = Applications/Foo.app/foo1.png
  [1] = Applications/Foo.app/foo2.png
/Applications/Bar.app => 
  [0] = Applications/Bar.app/bar1.png
  [1] = Applications/Bar.app/bar2.png
/Applications/Setup.app => 
  [0] = Applications/Setup.app/IDStore@2x.png
  [1] = Applications/Setup.app/IDMusic New@2x.png
  [2] = Applications/Setup.app/IDMessages@2x.png
```